# What are some methods to convert time series data into images for CNN?

Tags: time-series, cnn, image

I am working on a project where I have specific time series data which I would like to convert to images. I have investigated various methods, such as Markov Transition Fields, Gramian Angular Fields, and Recurrence Plots. I have already applied both MTF and GAF. However, RP does not seem applicable to my data. From my understanding, RP requires data that is periodic or has recurring states, while my data is more of a single period only. More specifically, my data is electrochemical data obtained from DPV and EIS experiments. Are there any other image conversion techniques I could investigate? Also, is it true that some techniques would not be applicable to certain data (by applicable I mean relevant and could be used to train a CNN model, yielding good results).

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe Spectrograms?

Comment: I agree with the earlier comment about a spectrogram, but why force this into a format appropriate for a convolutional neural network?